# Why do i get this error ? Could not convert from <brace-enclosed initializer list> to 'std::vector<>'

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm using an ARM microcontroller and compiler that supports C++11

I have a class described as following:

```
class commands 
{
public:
    string cmd_str;
    void (*fktPtr)(void);
};
```

The diag object is part of the Diag Class

```
class Diag
{
public:
void reset(void);
}

Diag diag;
```

The toggle function is a standalone function in the code:

```
void toggle_pin(void);
```

Then I have defined a vector of commands called the cmdlist:

```
vector<commands> cmdlist = {

{"togg",     toggle_pin }, // this works
{"rst",      diag.reset}, // this gives an error. why ?
{"rst1",     [](){diag.reset();}}, // this also works
}
```

The error:

```
main.cpp:81:1: error: could not convert '{{"togg", toggle_pin}, {"rst", diag.Diag::reset}}, {"rst1",<lambda closure object><lambda()>{}} from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::vector<commands>'
```

Why doesn't the initializer list support methods from an object, but supports regular functions/lambda functions ?

Comment: What is "commands"? Maybe you need a ref to the method like &Diag::reset

Comment: 1. To access a function from a class scope, use `&Diag::reset` syntax, 2. A non-static member function cannot be converted to a function pointer

Comment: @Holt: In the code shown, `diag` is global (file scope), and the lambda can access it without capture.

Comment: @BenVoigt Oh, did not see that ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has nothing to do with initialization lists or vectors, you can get the same error from

```
void (*fktPtr)(void) = diag.reset;
```

You have two issues, one is that you are missing the `&` to create a function pointer.  There's an implicit conversion for bare functions to function pointers; there is no such conversion for member functions.

So then we have:

```
void (*fktPtr1)(void) = &toggle_pin; // works
void (*fktPtr2)(void) = &Diag::reset; // doesn't
```

Now, you have a problem of incompatible types.  The address of a non-static member function has type *pointer to member function*, unlike bare functions and static member functions (these still need explicit `&ClassName::FunctionName` but yield a normal function pointer).  You can't convert a pointer-to-member into a normal function pointer.

Part of the problem is that the pointer-to-member function needs a target object (sometimes called *hidden `this` parameter*).  The C++ way of setting that in advance is with `std::bind`, but you still don't get an ordinary function pointer.

The lambda results in an ordinary function (the pointer ends up in your vector) which retrieves the target object from a global variable and calls a function on it.  That's legal, but might as well not have a class at all, since you're locked to that single instance named by the global variable.

If you want something closer to "delegates" found in languages such as C#, that store the function and target object together, try

```
std::function<void (void)> fktPtr;
```

instead of a bare function pointer.  This is compatible with bare functions, static member functions, bound instance member functions, non-capturing lambdas, and capturing lambdas.